# alternative to nslookup in rhel7?

Tags: command-line, dns

`nslookup` does not come preinstalled in RHEL 7 Beta. I noticed even `dig` and `host` was not pre installed. I read couple of links which mentions `nslookup` is dead/deprecated, so is there an alternative for `nslookup` introduced in RHEL7 which comes preinstalled?

Comment: Have you tried "dig". I don't know if it's preinstalled by default.

Comment: What's wrong with installing `bind-utils`? RHEL7 simply doesn't have everything installed by default.

Comment: in official RHEL7 OpenStack image there is no nslookup/dig/host. You need to use "getent hosts"

Answer (score 59):

Have you tried `getent hosts`?

```
[root@test ~]# getent hosts unix.stackexchange.com
198.252.206.140 unix.stackexchange.com
```

It's not give full details like nameserver,other resource record like other tools (`dig`) do, so if you want full details then you need to install `bind-utils` package. or just using `ping` to know ip

Answer (score 5):

Actually the decision to obsolete `nslookup` has been reverted, at least in the version provided by ISC. Source: [bind9/9.9.0a3/CHANGES](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.9.0a3/CHANGES) (Entry #1700)